# Search multiple dropdown lists

Tags: search, drop-down-list, multiple-data

I'm looking for examples of searching multiple dropdowns at the same time. For example, say you didn't know if Texas was a state or country and you started searching in the Country dropdown for Texas. I'm looking to update the Country with USA and the state with Texas.

These aren't exactly the fields I'm working but it's a good analogy.

I haven't been able to find a good example of how this might look.

Answer (score 4):

If using multiple drop-downs isn't necessary, I would use a single text box that would ask the location. While I am entering the Texas word, it can suggest "Texas, USA". Because entering country name will not automatically fill the other drop-down or many countries around the world doesn't have states. Providing a text box for location with suggestions is easier to adapt for different countries or situations.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Part of our issue is that the child field may not always be present, but we could find a way to make this work with a textbox either way.

Answer (score -3):

before nothing is a example basic, some so ? some so? that is I understanded that you need, but my recommend for this case is use location maps some so : 
[image]
[image: example]